# How to access object set by server on client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using `node` with `express` and I want access object sent by server.
For example

server side:

```
router.get('/some_page/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('some_page', {
        data: {"somevar1":"somevalue", "somevar2":"somevalue2"}
    });
});
```

client side javascript:

```
var objSentFromSrv = ??? // here i want this object and then perform some action on it
```

Is this possible/legitimate?

**EDIT:**

I'm using `handlebars` as template engine.

Figured out somehow.

```
function middlewareAppendingLocals(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.layoutV = myValue;

    next();
}

router.post('/page/', middlewareAppendingLocals, (req, res) => {
    res.render('page_to_render');
});
```

In my case this variable is from database and I'm giving it based on id posted from antoher page. But still how can I access it from javascript, not only form .hbs layout file.

Then page_to_render have and I can you handlebars {{}} to get it.

Comment: you should note what templating language you're using

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode the object as JSON like this:

```
router.get('/some_page/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        data: {"somevar1":"somevalue", "somevar2":"somevalue2"}
    }));
});
```

and then use AJAX on the front-end, using jQuery you can use

```
$.get('/some_page/', function(data) {
    var objSentFromSrv = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

or shorter:

```
$.getJSON('/some_page/', function(data) {
    var objSentFromSrv = data;
});
```

Comment: Isn't it sending data twice? First when you enter URL in browser, second when the script start to execute?

Comment: Your html page with script shouldn't be `/some_page/` it's only for returning JSON.

Comment: that is not correct. The express route does not indicate what the return type is, but it's usually HTML. The "data" object is what is passed into the template.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is possible and legitimate. Assuming you are using [EJS](http://ejs.co/), add a line like this to your template:

```
<script>
    const objSentFromSrv = <%-JSON.stringify(data)%>;
</script>
```

If you're using a different templating engine, you'll just need to look up the specific syntax on how to serialize objects.

AjAX is overkill for this use-case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AngularJS as your front end service, you can create a controller and have it inject `$scope` and `$http` to get the data. For example:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('mainController', ($scope, $http) => {
    $scope.data= {};

    $scope.getData = function() {
        $http.get('/some_route/')
            .success((data) => {
                $scope.data = data;
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };
});
```

And then in the front end, call `getData()`.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: I'm not using AngularJS or any other frameworks, beside expressjs.

Answer (score 0):

Your templating engine is going to take the arguments passed to that render call and produce HTML (often) or JSON.  It's not really sending objects, just text data.

If you're looking to change the state of some object that exists on the server side, you'll want to create some sort of API to do that.  Send data down to the client, make changes to that data, then send it back to the server to be incorporated into the original object.

Comment: I just want to do some things on client side, and don't need to send back object. So how can i access it with `handlebars` for example? I mean that on client side have some logic doing things on object, not only render it via {{}}.

Comment: If you could show an example of the original object, and what you want to do with it once it gets to the client, that would be helpful

Comment: My main goal is to render saved template. Template contains: rows, cols, array of size rows times cols, contating some data. Now i want to render that array in some nice way. I know that in `hbs` I can just {{each ...}, but this is like 2D array, and I want to place rows and cols. So I'm miising modulo conditional operation to select if it is row or col.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Handlebar js and found to get server-side data at client side Javascript just using {{{ server-side JSON }}
`

Server-side Code  send JSON adminData on the client side

```
return h.view('reports' ,{ adminData: request.auth.credentials});
```

Client side Code to get adminData inside script tag

```
 console.log("{{{adminData}}}")
```